# Box 'SessionAuthenticated' event not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, box

I'm not able to get the new Refresh/Access tokens once the previous ones has expired, is there a way to do it using sdk, 'cause now again i've to go to https://box-token-generator.herokuapp.com/ to re-create the refresh/access tokens.  This is code sample

```
        var boxConfig = new BoxConfig(clientId, clientSecret, uriRedirect);
        OAuthSession oAuthSession = new OAuthSession(accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn, tokenType);
        BoxClient boxClient = new BoxClient(boxConfig);
        boxClient.Auth.SessionAuthenticated += Auth_SessionAuthenticated;
        boxClient.Auth.SessionInvalidated += Auth_SessionInvalidated;

        boxClient = new BoxClient(boxConfig, oAuthSession);
```

Answer (score 0):

please use following

1>

```
client.Auth.SessionAuthenticated += new EventHandler  < SessionAuthenticatedEventArgs > (Auth_SessionAuthenticated);
```

2:
Also please add following method

```
void Auth_SessionAuthenticated(object sender, SessionAuthenticatedEventArgs e)
{
   string boxAccessToken = e.Session.AccessToken;
   string boxRefreshToken = e.Session.RefreshToken;
}
```